# Match last value in column with blanks on multiple criteria

Tags: excel, match

I have a table (T_Data) that - for the sake of this post - is structured similar to the following:

| StoreID | DateStamp | Inventory | Sold |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0000001 | 2020-12-26 | 10000 | 500 |
| 0000002 | 2020-12-26 |  | 100 |
| 0000001 | 2020-12-27 |  | 400 |
| 0000002 | 2020-12-27 | 5000 | 200 |
| 0000001 | 2020-12-28 |  | 400 |
| 0000002 | 2020-12-28 |  | 200 |
| 0000001 | 2020-12-29 |  | 400 |
| 0000002 | 2020-12-29 |  | 200 |
| 0000001 | 2020-12-30 |  | 400 |
| 0000002 | 2020-12-30 |  | 200 |

Inventory is a physical count, which happens once a month per store, but the date may vary.  I need to return the last physical count per StoreID.  I can leverage the following for ALL stores, but I can't figure out how to translate that to use multiple criteria:

=MATCH(9.99999999999999E+307,T_Data[Inventory])

(Returns 5000)

I'm using Excel 2016, so Sort is out of the question.  I'm also avoiding VBA because it'll cause issues with my staff figuring out how to get around warnings.

Comment: why are you trying to match using scientific notation?

Comment: I'd use a lookup Boolean structure. E.g: `=LOOKUP(2,1/((DataRange1=Criteria1)*(DataRange2=Criteria2)),ReturnRange)`. Though I'm not sure what exactly your criteria is.

Comment: @ashleedawg by looking up a ridiculously large number and using the default lookup type it will return the last cell with a number.

Comment: ummm ok.  I can think of better ways to find the last cell (ie,[`MAXIFS`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/maxifs-function-dfd611e6-da2c-488a-919b-9b6376b28883)?), but also wouldn't looking up just a "large" number rather than "ridiculously" large would also do the trick, no?  Unless some inventory items actually have "10 centillion" items in stock...

Comment: @ashleedawg my default for this type is `1E+99` which as you stated is usually sufficient, and much easier to type.  And MATCH is much quicker than LOOKUP if a single lookup.  One off formula will not see a difference but a column full would.

Comment: @ashleedawg as Scott points out, any sufficiently large number would suffice.  I was trying to avoid the opposite debate if I posited using a smaller number in my example.  :D

Comment: @ashleedawg Side note:  MAXIFS is not in 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LOOKUP:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/((T_Data[Inventory]<>"")*(T_Data[StoreID]=F4)),T_Data[Inventory])
```

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly!  I can leverage this then to get the date as well, which was a secondary issue.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use `MAXIFS` to find the date of the last non-blank inventory and then use `XLOOKUP` to find the Inventory on that date. I think `XLOOKUP` is in Excel2016.

[image]

Formula for `G2`:

```
=MAXIFS($B$2:$B$11,$C$2:$C$11,"<>",$A$2:$A$11,F2)
```

Formula for `H2`:

```
=XLOOKUP(F2&G2,$A$2:$A$11&$B$2:$B$11,$C$2:$C$11)
```